# Publishing Delphi applications to the Microsoft Store

Tags: delphi

I would like to publish my first Delphi application in the Microsoft Store.

Do applications published in the Microsoft Store also have to be signed with a commercial certificate?

When I launch my application, the user should not be shown that the application is from an unspecified developer, etc.

Comment: Here is a blog article from Embacadero about the necessary steps. It also includes links to some docwiki documentation! https://blogs.embarcadero.com/learn-how-to-deploy-your-delphi-applications-to-the-microsoft-store/

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you need a code signing certificate. You can get a standard or an [extended validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) certificate. The last one is more expensive, but since you are vetted more thoroughly, MS also values these higher.<sup>*</sup>

Even with that, you still have the risk of your app getting flagged by Windows Defender as a potentially unwanted application until sufficient people have downloaded it and marked it as safe (google e.g. "defender flagging downloaded installer")

MS itself gives more information at [Publish Windows apps and games](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/publish/), and note that you need to supply a [MSIX, MSI or EXE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/publish/publish-your-app/overview?pivots=store-installer-msix).

BTW Embarcadero also has some information about publishing as an APPX and to the Micrososft Store:

- [Windows 11: A Beautiful Meteor Will Wipe Out The Dinosaurs](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/windows-11-a-beautiful-meteor-will-wipe-out-the-dinosaurs/) about Windows 11 and app stores
- [VCL Integration with WinAPI, COM & ShellAPI, and WinRT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQNb0zZradc)  YouTube video, `TWindowsStore` discussed at 37:00

<sup>* Do not confuse this with the three levels of website certificates, e.g. [described here](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/types-of-ssl-certificates/).</sup>